# Print Two 1 dimensional arrays in fortran

Tags: fortran

I have two 1 dimensional arrays.
I would like to print the contents as follows.

> array1:- name age country
>   array2:-a 12 china b 13 chile c 14 india

output

```
name = a age =12 country = china name = b age =13 country = chile name = c age =14 country = india
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be easier if designed to use an array of structures rather than a structure of arrays. The structure of arrays approach looks kind of like

```
program nml1
   implicit none
   type info(length)
      integer, len :: length
      character(20) name(length)
      integer age(length)
      character(20) country(length)
   end type info
   type(info(:)), allocatable :: class
   namelist /my_data/ class
   class = info(3)([character(20)::'a','b','c'],[12,13,14], &
      [character(20)::'china','chile','india'])
   write(*,nml=my_data)
end program nml1
```

Or maybe

```
program nml2
   implicit none
   type info(length)
      integer, len :: length
      character(20) name(length)
      integer age(length)
      character(20) country(length)
   end type info
   type(info(:)), allocatable :: class
   namelist /my_data/ class
   allocate(info(3)::class)
   class%name = [character(20)::'a','b','c']
   class%age = [12,13,14]
   class%country = [character(20)::'china','chile','india']
   write(*,nml=my_data)
end program nml2
```

But I can't seem to get either of these to compile with gfortran or ifort. My fault or compiler bugs?

But that's not a big problem because I was gonna recommend the array of structures approach anyhow. In this case instead of having 3 arrays of scalar data packed in a structure (or just free for that matter) we pack all relevant data for each student in a structure and create an array of such structures. Here is what that looks like:

```
program nml
   implicit none
   type info
      character(20) name
      integer age
      character(20) country
   end type info
   type(info), allocatable :: class(:)
   namelist /my_data/ class
   class = [info('a',12,'china'),info('b',13,'chile'),info('c',14,'india')]
   write(*,nml=my_data)
end program nml
```

Now, the nice thing about this approach is that not only does it compile, but the data are regurgitated automatically in the right order and with labels via `namelist' I/O so that if this format is good enough we don't have to write any fancy output code. Output with gfortran is:

```
&MY_DATA
 CLASS(1)%NAME="a                   ",
 CLASS(1)%AGE=12         ,
 CLASS(1)%COUNTRY="china               ",
 CLASS(2)%NAME="b                   ",
 CLASS(2)%AGE=13         ,
 CLASS(2)%COUNTRY="chile               ",
 CLASS(3)%NAME="c                   ",
 CLASS(3)%AGE=14         ,
 CLASS(3)%COUNTRY="india               ",
 /
```